# Filling roles in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have problem with filling user roles and i cant find solution. I have list of roles for user but i dont know how to send it to the model. My code:

ApplicationUser

```
    namespace WebApp.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser() : base() { }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ApplicationRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    }
}
```

ApplicationRole

```
namespace WebApp.Models
    {
        public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
        {
            public ApplicationRole() : base() { }

            public ApplicationRole(string roleName) : base(roleName) { }

            public ApplicationRole(string roleName, string description, DateTime creationDate) : base(roleName)
            {
                this.Description = description;
                this.CreationDate = creationDate;
            }

            public string Description { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

AdminController

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> UserList(ApplicationUser ApplicationUser)
        {
            var users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();

            foreach (var v in users)
            {
                var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(v);
                var user = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();

                user.UserRoles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(v);

                _context.SaveChanges();
            }

            var usersList = _context.Users.ToList();

            return await Task.Run(() => View(usersList));
        }
```

> user.UserRoles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(v);

cause error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

// EDIT error caused by missing asynch but now the error is

> Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)   WebApp

How to convert data to fill UserRoles?

Comment: The direct error is just a missing `await`

Comment: @HenkHolterman fixed missing await but conversion error is still

Comment: GetRolesAsync returns a list of strings (or maybe IdentityRole), you will need a converter .

Comment: var user = _context.Users.Include( x => x.UserRoles).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);   just include the roles of the user in your query, so then you can access them with user.UserRoles

Comment: That comment by @mdln97 points to another problem with your model: UserRoles is visible to EF, you now have 2 sets of roles. I don't think you want that. You cannot use your own RoleType in Identity, only the User type.

Comment: @MarcinAWK I am not sure of what you actually wanting. You are trying to get the userList with associated roles but this `_context.SaveChanges();` doing here. Please make your requirement clear, surely there is a solution.

Comment: I'm looking for best practice way to create list of users in the tables with their roles like 'User1 user1@oo.com Role1, role2, role3 ' and create edit button to assign or remove roles for every user.